How to get User primary phone number from Clerk on expo
I'm currently implementing 2FA authentication using a phone number, and I'm attempting to obtain the user's primary phone number from the clerk. This information should be acquired after a successful sign-in with email and password. Is there a method to retrieve this data within the current session, or would it necessitate the creation of an API for this purpose?
const onSignInPress = async () => {
   if (!isLoaded) {       return;     }
setLoading(true); 

    try {
      const completeSignIn = await signIn.create({
        identifier: emailAddress,
        password,
      });
    
    
      console.log(user);
    
      await completeSignIn.prepareFirstFactor({
        phoneNumberId: '',
        strategy: 'phone_code',
      })
    
      let number = user?.primaryPhoneNumber?.toString() || '';

      router.push({ pathname: '/verificationPhone/[phone], params: { phone: number } });     } 
catch (err: any) 
{       alert(err.errors[0].message);     } 
finally {       setLoading(false);     }
};

